# .htaccess remove .html and force redirect to extensionless url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I'm trying to remove `.html` extensions from URLs and to have 302 redirection to the extensionless URLs like this:

http://example.com/file.html -> http://example.com/file

I have looked at so many stackoverflow answers, tried them but unfortunately no success. I came out with this and I don't understand why it does not work:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.html$
RewriteRule (.*)\.html$ /$1 [R=302,L]  

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.html$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

Where the first block should redirect to the extensionless version and the second block should find the file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use %{THE_REQUEST} here to prevent rewrite loop error. otherwise without THE_REQUEST variable Rule keeps rewriting file => file.html=>file=>file.html..

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /%1 [R=302,L]  

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```